# How to store inkPicture control content in SQL Server table and read the content back to inkPicture control?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2010, adodb

I have an MS Access 2010 application. I have a form with an inkPicture control named InkSign, where the user can put a signature. I store the content of the inkPicture control in een variant variable named sig like this:

```
sig = Me.InkSign.Ink.save()
```

Now I can read back this variant data into the control using:

```
Dim newInk As New InkDisp
newInk.Load sig
Me.InkSign.Ink.DeleteStrokes
Me.InkSign.InkEnabled = False
Set InkSign.Ink = newInk
Me.InkSign.InkEnabled = True
```

I want to persist and read back the signature data in a SQL Server database table.

I have tried this:

```
Private Sub btnSaveSig_Click()
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 

    sig = Me.InkSign.Ink.save()

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rst
        '.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "SELECT * FROM sign WHERE signID = 1", cnnC, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
        If .BOF And .EOF Then .AddNew
        .Fields("signDate") = Date
        .Fields("signedBy") = "Pipo"
        .Fields("sign") = sig
        .Fields("docType") = "so"
        .Fields("docID") = "1"
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
    MsgBox "signature saved"

End Sub
```

The column `sign` is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. The data gets stored, but looks like Chinese characters. But is this the correct way to store this binary data?

I am trying to read back the data, but it fails on this line: newInk.Load sig

```
Private Sub LoadSignature()
    Dim newInk As New InkDisp

    sig = Nz(cLookup("sign", "sign", "signID = 1"), "")
    If IsEmpty(sig) Then Exit Sub

    newInk.Load sig
    Me.InkSign.Ink.DeleteStrokes
    Me.InkSign.InkEnabled = False
    Set InkSign.Ink = newInk
    Me.InkSign.InkEnabled = True
End Sub
```

The clookup function is a function that retrieves data from a SQL Server table.
The error I get is

> Invalid procedure call or argument

I think I should use a ADO stream object to write and read back the data. But I do not know how.

Can anyone help me to get this code working?

Thanks, Emphyrio

Comment: Use `varbinary(MAX)` instead of `nvarchar(MAX)` to store binary data.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for showing me this obvious solution. Changing the datatype to varbinary(max) did the trick. No need for a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try, not tested.

```
Private Sub btnSaveSig_Click()
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream
    Dim fn As String

    sig = Me.InkSign.Ink.Save()

    'Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set oStream = New ADODB.Stream

    fn = "c:\myImageFile" '<~~"Your image file path"

    With oStream
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile fn
    End With

    If oStream.Size > 0 Then
        With rst
            '.CursorLocation = adUseClient
            .Open "SELECT * FROM sign WHERE signID = 1", cnnC, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
            If .BOF And .EOF Then .AddNew
            .Fields("signDate") = Date
            .Fields("signedBy") = "Pipo"
            .Fields("sign") = oStream.Read '<~~ image read
            .Fields("docType") = "so"
            .Fields("docID") = "1"
            .Update
            .Close
        End With
    End If
    Set rst = Nothing
    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing
    MsgBox "signature saved"

End Sub
```